# The object referenced by the java:comp/env/HRONLINEFSDEV2 JNDI name could not be instantiated in Liberty

Tags: java, websphere, jndi, websphere-liberty

Here Am trying to migrating application from WAS 8 to Liberty. While running the application am getting error about JNDI lookup,

**ERROR**

> CWNEN1001E: The object referenced by the java:comp/env/HRONLINEFSDEV2
>   JNDI name could not be instantiated. If the reference name maps to a
>   JNDI name in the deployment descriptor bindings for the application
>   performing the JNDI lookup, make sure that the JNDI name mapping in
>   the deployment descriptor binding is correct. If the JNDI name mapping
>   is correct, make sure the target resource can be resolved with the
>   specified name relative to the default initial context. [Root
>   exception is com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException:
>   CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the
>   java:comp/env/HRONLINEFSDEV2 reference.  The exception message was:
>   CWNEN1004E: The server was unable to find the HRONLINEFSDEV2 default
>   binding with the javax.sql.DataSource type for the
>   java:comp/env/HRONLINEFSDEV2 reference.]

**WEB.XML**

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>
    </description>
    <res-ref-name>HRONLINEFSDEV2</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

**IBM-WEB-BND.XML**

```
<resource-ref name="HRONLINEFSDEV2" binding-name="jdbc/hronline/ds_FSDEV2"/>
```

**SERVER.XML**

```
<dataSource id="HRONLINEFSDEV2" jndiName="jdbc/hronline/ds_FSDEV2" type="javax.sql.DataSource" jdbcDriverRef="Oracle_12.1.0.2">
        <properties.oracle databaseName="SF304D03" serverName="ECCDB1382.ECC1Q.FORD.COM" portNumber="1521" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ECCDB1382.ECC1Q.FORD.COM:1521:SF304D03" statementCacheSize="50" name="HRONLINEFSDEV2" description="Data source template"/>
        <connectionManager agedTimeout="1200" connectionTimeout="180" maxIdleTime="1800" maxPoolSize="100" minPoolSize="1" reapTime="300"/>
    </dataSource>
```

**JAVA FILE**

```
initContext = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/hronline/ds_FSDEV2");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the binding file to associate a resource reference in web.xml with an server resource in server.xml, the `res-ref-name` in web.xml needs to match the `name` in IBM-WEB-BND.XML, ie, change `<resource-ref name="HRONLINEFSDEV2"` to `<resource-ref name="HRONLINEFSQA2"` (or vice versa).  Also, your java code needs to lookup the jndi name specified in the binding file by `binding-name="jdbc/hronline/ds_FSDEV2"` like this

ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/hronline/ds_FSDEV2);

Comment: I changed as HRONLINEFSDEV2 in WEB.XML but in I given "ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/HRONLINEFSDEV2");" but it throwing same error

Comment: You're using an incorrect JNDI name to lookup the resource, read the last sentence and lookup code of my answer above.

Comment: Please edit your question above to indicate your changes.